# For loop skipping two iterations with Thread.Sleep

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I made an android application that simply calls the number range you enter. 
Starts with starting number you enter and finishes with the "finish" number you enter. Application automatically hangs up after 7 seconds of ringing. 
Code is below.

```
public void onClick(View view){

    EditText starte = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.start);
    EditText finishe = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.finish);
    EditText prefixes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.prefixes);

    String prefix = prefixes.getText().toString();
    /** Get Telephone number String **/
    int startOriginal = Integer.parseInt(starte.getText().toString());
    int finish = Integer.parseInt(finishe.getText().toString());

    for (int start = startOriginal; start<=finish; start++) {

        startCall(prefix, Integer.toString(start));

        try {
            Thread.sleep(7000);
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    new CallUtilities("endcall");
}

private void startCall(String prefix, String nr){

    Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL");

    Uri data = Uri.parse("tel:"+ prefix + nr);

    /** Setting intent data */
    intent.setData(data);

    /** Starting the caller activity by the implicit intent */
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

CallUtilities class is written by my end is simply ends the call via reflection methods. Now my problem is that when you enter a starting number and a finishing number the app always seems to call the first number for example 1 and after hanging it up it goes straight to 3 and then to 4 and 5 and so on like it should do. Any idea on what is wrong?
Also is it possible to use DisconnectCause here to get the reason of disconnect in case calls hangs up prematurely?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a recipe for disaster. For a few reasons.

You are (assuming `onClick(View v)` runs on the UI Thread) attempting to sleep the UI Thread.

If the UI Thread hangs for longer than 5 seconds, it will cause an ANR.

Additionally, you appear to be attempting to launch multiple Activities at the same time. This is certainly not the right way to be designing your App.

Not to mention using Reflection to access core Android components to end the calls. That may cause issues for your App in the future.

My suggestion for the multiple Activities / sleep problem:

1. Remove the loop
2. Store next attempted number
3. Run the call function
4. In [onActivityResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent)) you can determine the next number to try
5. Go to 2. (make sure to include an end condition!

Comment: In that case is ASyncTask a way to go?

Comment: AsyncTask is irrelevant in my case, as nothing is happening in the background.